# Replicate data from MySQL to Amazon S3

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a populated local MySQL database. I want to replicate all my data to an Amazon S3 bucket. Using the query "SELECT * FROM analytics;" I would have all the data.
Specifically, I am using this gem:

```
gem install mysql2
```

How could I, then, introduce all data into Amazon S3?

Comment: You might consider [AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) for that? It supports on-premises MySQL as a [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Sources.html) and S3 as a [target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Targets.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can take dump of the mysql table and compress it.

```
mysqldump db_name table_name | gzip > table_name.sql.gz
```

Then can upload the file to S3 bucket, either manually or using aws cli.

Or can use [AWS data migration service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html) with S3 as target.

Comment: I would actually recommend against DMS as its crazy expensive for the job its doing. You can't pause the migration instance and its running 24/7.  A simple scheduled fargate job or similar is much more cost efficient for this task.

Comment: @LRutten, Can schedule the job of mysqldump+s3 sync, if not willing to pay for DMS